# Remove Top Bar of Collection View

Tags: uicollectionview, uinavigationbar, cell, space, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a small emoji collection view that is displayed when users tap an emoji button. I would like to get rid of the top bar space so that the background, for example, is all blue. I tried making `top bar` on storyboard `None.`. How can I remove this space?

[image]
[image]

[image]

```
import UIKit

class EmojiViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

    let emojiImages = [...the pics...]

    var selectedIndex: Int?
    var estimateWidth = 100.0
    var cellMarginSize = 10.0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.emojiImages.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "emojiCell", for: indexPath) as! EmojiViewCell
        let emoji = emojiImages[indexPath.row]
        cell.emojiImage.image = UIImage(named: emojiImages[indexPath.row])

        if selectedIndex == indexPath.row {
            cell.backgroundColor =  UIColor.red
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            UserDefaults.standard.set(emoji, forKey: "emojiPicked")
        }else{
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        }
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        selectedIndex = selectedIndex == indexPath.row ? nil : indexPath.row
        collectionView.reloadData()
    }
}

extension EmojiViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: 40, height: 40)
    }
}
```

Comment: are you using UICollectionViewController and your collectionViewController has an UINavigationController? I would like to help but you need to show some code base and some more details.

Comment: added! and yes there was a navigation controller but even when I deleted it looked the same (I added the pic from storyboard above) @ImrulKayes

Comment: did you use **self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)** this line of code in your **viewWillAppear** method? and I can see your collectionView Under EmojiViewController on storyboard but you didn't make a connection of your collectionView on EmojiViewController.swift file. how exactly you configure? It seems something going on your StoryBoard.

Comment: my pleasure! by the way, you are using present as popover segue. Are you building an app for only iPad? just curious :)

Comment: I only need a handful of emojis so I thought it would be good to just display them in like a container pointing to something they touch which then shows the emojis. Not sure how else to display them. It's for IOS.